Changing the hanging indent changes the tab distance - how to prevent?
I have a hanging indent for a paragraph.
I then increase the hanging indent, and as a result of that, the tab distance changes as well, to match the hanging indent.
How can I prevent the tab distance from changing?
Here are screenshots with the Paragraph dialog over it, showing the only difference between the two. There is a tab between the first and second words (The and quick). As you can see, by changing the hanging size, the tab shortens to match the indent. This only happens when the indent reaches the tab, in this case when it's larger than 0.6.



I can't reproduce the problem. Maybe screencaps showing actual text (including invisible characters) and including the ruler could be helpful here.

@cybernetic.nomad See edit.

I see. The tab will go the the tab location or the location of the hanging indent, whichever comes first. you can either type in a second tab, or move the hanging indent past the first tab location.
